# I am not able to post form on same page

Tags: php

Here are the codes.

**Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="search">
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" alt="Publish"> Publish</a></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" alt="Edit"> Edit </a></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="draft" id="draft" alt="Save as Draft"> Save as Draft</a></div>
</form>
```

**Post**

```
<?php
    
if ($_POST['publish'] == 'publish'){
echo '<script>alert("Publish"); </script>';
}
if ($_POST['edit'] == 'publish'){
echo '<script>alert("edit"); </script>';
}
if ($_POST['draft'] == 'publish'){
echo 'draft';
}   
    ?>
```

If I click on any button nothing happens. I am not getting anything nor any error. Nothing appears in firebug as well.

Comment: how can you submit form with anchor without js. OR without get

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure about that please advise.

Comment: please write first with which are you wants to submit form using anchor or using submit buttons? you are  using anchor and type submit in a same.

Comment: There are 3 button for different purposes. I just simply want when i click on specific button it fire specific code/event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted to submit to the same page. Try giving the page name in your action

```
<form method="POST" action="yourpage.php" id="search">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {

   echo '<script>alert("Publish"); </script>';
}

if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

   echo '<script>alert("edit"); </script>';
}

if (isset($_POST['draft'])) {

   echo 'draft';
}   

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

use button instead of links

like

```
<input type="submit" ..... />
```

like this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="publish" id="publish" alt="Publish" value="Publish" />
```

You will get data then

and try to on error reporting in php.ini file

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a submit n
Button. `<input type=submit name="submit">` also, specify `action attribute` in form tag to your Php script.

Answer (score 2):

**First** thing you can not use **type="submit" as attribute in your anchor tag.**

**Second** if you wants to submit button using input type as submit then use the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    if (isset($_POST['publish'])){
    echo '<script>alert("Publish"); </script>'; 
    }
    if (isset($_POST['edit'])){
    echo '<script>alert("edit"); </script>'; 
    }
    if (isset($_POST['draft'])){
    echo '<script>alert("Draft"); </script>'; 
    }   
}   
    ?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="search">
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" value="Publish"> </input></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit"> </input></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="draft" id="draft" value="Draft"> </input></div>
</form>
```

**Third,** In case if you really wants to use only anchor for submit then you have to use help of javascript function **submit()** and use the

> onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit();

in your anchor tag.

Comment: I got one issue. When i submit the page it is reloading. I don't want to reload the page. Is there anything i can do?

Comment: You have to utilize Ajax feature. Use the link http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/ OR http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form1.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo '<script>alert("Publish"); </script>';
}
    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="" id="search">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```